# Connecting to existing Google Chromecast Session from Android (for generic remote control)

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I am creating a generic Chromecast remote control app. Most of the guts of the app are already created and I've managed to get Chromecast volume control working (by connecting to a Chromecast device along side another app that is casting - YouTube for example).

What I've having difficult with is performing other media commands such as play, pause, seek, etc.

Use case example:
1. User opens YouTube on their android device and starts casting a video.
2. User opens my app and connects to the same Chromecast device.
3. Volume control from my app (works now)
4. Media control (play, pause, etc) (does not yet work)

I found the Cast api reference that explains that you can sendMessage(ApiClient, namespace, message) with media commands; however the "message" (JSON) requires the sessionId of the current application (Youtube in this case). I have tried the following, but the connection to the current application always fails; status.isSuccess() is always false:

```
Cast.CastApi
                    .joinApplication(mApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(
                                        Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                                    Status status = result.getStatus();
                                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                        ApplicationMetadata applicationMetadata = result
                                                .getApplicationMetadata();
                                        sessionId = result.getSessionId();
                                        String applicationStatus = result
                                                .getApplicationStatus();
                                        boolean wasLaunched = result
                                                .getWasLaunched();

                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "Joined Application with sessionId: "
                                                        + sessionId
                                                        + " Application Status: "
                                                        + applicationStatus);

                                    } else {
                                        // teardown();
                                        Log.e(TAG,
                                                "Could not join application: "
                                                        + status.toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Is is possible to get the sessionId of an already running cast application from a generic remote control app (like the one I am creating)? If so, am I right in my assumption that I can then perform media commands on the connected Chromecast device using something like this:

```
JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
            message.put("mediaSessionId", sessionId);
            message.put("requestId", 9999);
            message.put("type", "PAUSE");

            Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient,
            "urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media", message.toString());
```

Update:
I have tried the recommendations provided by @Ali Naddaf but unfortunately they are not working. After creating mRemoteMediaPlayer in onCreate, I also do requestStatus(mApiClient) in the onConnected callback (in the ConnectionCallbacks). When I try to .play(mApiClient) I get an IllegalStateException stating that there is no current media session. Also, I tried doing joinApplication and in the callback performed result.getSessionId; which returns null.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments and answers:

- You can get the sessionId from the callback of `launchApplication` or `joinApplication`; in the "`onResult(result)`", you can get the sessionId from: `result.getSessionId()`
- YouTube is still not on the official SDK so YMMV, for apps using official SDK, you should be able to use the above approach (most of it)
- Why are you trying to set up a message yourself? Why not building a `RemoteMediaPlayer` and using play/pause that is provided there? Whenever you are working with the media playback through the official channel, always use the `RemoteMediaPlayer` (don't forget to call `requestStatus()` on it after creating it).

Comment: I will try these ideas and report back. I really appreciate the response.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to be working. After creating mRemoteMediaPlayer in onCreate, I also do requestStatus(mApiClient) in the onConnected callback (in the ConnectionCallbacks). When I try to .play(mApiClient) I get an IllegalStateException stating that there is no current media session. Also, I tried doing joinApplication and in the callback performed result.getSessionId; which returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , First you have to save sesionId and CastDevice device id 
and when remove app from background and again open app please check is there sessionId then call bello line.
Cast.CastApi.joinApplication(apiClient, APP_ID,sid).setResultCallback(connectionResultCallback);
if you get success result then need to implement further process in connectionResultCallback listener.

//Get selected device which you selected before

```
    @Override
    public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
        //          Log.d("Route Added", "onRouteAdded");
      /*  if (router.getRoutes().size() > 1)
            Toast.makeText(homeScreenActivity, "'onRouteAdded :: " + router.getRoutes().size() + " -- " + router.getRoutes().get(1).isSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            Toast.makeText(homeScreenActivity, "'onRouteAdded :: " + router.getRoutes(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        if (router != null && router.getRoutes() != null && router.getRoutes().size() > 1) {
            // Show the button when a device is discovered.
            //     Toast.makeText(homeScreenActivity, "'onRouteAdded :: " + router.getRoutes().size() + " -- " + router.getRoutes().get(1).isSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            titleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            castName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(route.getExtras());

            routeInfoArrayList = router.getRoutes();
            titleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!isCastConnected) {

                String deid = MyPref.getInstance(homeScreenActivity).readPrefs(MyPref.CAST_DEVICE_ID);
                for (int i = 0; i < routeInfoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (routeInfoArrayList.get(i).getExtras() != null && CastDevice.getFromBundle(routeInfoArrayList.get(i).getExtras()).getDeviceId().equalsIgnoreCase(deid)) {
                        selectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(routeInfoArrayList.get(i).getExtras());
                        routeInfoArrayList.get(i).select();
                        ReSelectedDevice(selectedDevice, routeInfoArrayList.get(i).getName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }





    }
```

//Reconnect google Api Client

public void reConnectGoogleApiClient() {

```
    if (apiClient == null) {

        Cast.CastOptions apiOptions = new
```

Cast.CastOptions.Builder(selectedDevice, castClientListener).build();

```
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptions)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(reconnectionCallback)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
                .build();

        apiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

// join Application

```
private final GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks reconnectionCallback = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
      //  Toast.makeText(homeScreenActivity, "" + isDeviceSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            String sid = MyPref.getInstance(homeScreenActivity).readPrefs(MyPref.CAST_SESSION_ID);
            String deid = MyPref.getInstance(homeScreenActivity).readPrefs(MyPref.CAST_DEVICE_ID);
            if (sid != null && deid != null && sid.length() > 0 && deid.length() > 0)
                Cast.CastApi.joinApplication(apiClient, APP_ID, sid).setResultCallback(connectionResultCallback);

            isApiConnected = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        isCastConnected = false;
        isApiConnected = false;


    }

};
```